# How to encrypt the password before on submit in wicket?

Tags: wicket

Now I am getting password user typed as string in model, I want to encrypt the password before on submit and set in model then I need to decrypt the encrypted password in server side?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? What kind of attack do you want to defend against?

Comment: Hi actually when I submit the form I get password user entered in model, someone hacked the system and able to see the password in the model. So I need to encrypt the password and set in model before submit.

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://github.com/brix/crypto-js to encrypt your password on the client side and then use the same crypto algorithms at the server side with Java to decrypt it.

But I don't see why you need to do this yourself. Just use HTTPS and there is no need of such manual work.

Comment: In fact if you don't serve your page via HTTPS, you're already in trouble, crypto or not. And if you do, client-side crypto is, as you say, pointless.

Comment: +1 Use https.. otherwise you have a leaky security abstraction in saving the key used to perform the encryption

Comment: What if a key logger is installed in the browser and my credentials are captured? I've seen some online banking sites do this despite using HTTPS.

Comment: Who installs the key logger ? The bank itself ? They already have your credentials - in the form submit.